# How to concatenate UIButton along with UIText

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, constraints, nslayoutconstraint

I want to add a `UIButton` at the end of a sentence in `UIView`.

Presently I have a `UILabel` to display text and a button next to it. Both are subviews to `UIView`. I get the desired o/p if the sentence spans to 2 lines.

How should I modify it, for it to work properly even if the text changes to 3 or 4 lines given that I cannot change the size of the `UIView` or the `UILabel`?

Comment: Add your done code.

Comment: you can do it using auto layout. you don't have to worry about number of lines also as it will adjust automatically.

Comment: make the button **center vertically** to the label in the storyboard

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear to me what you are trying to achieve... anyway maybe with autolayout you could solve your problem:
The button will be placed always on the bottom right corner of the label and the width of the label itself will span from  42 to the max available space...

[image]